# The one with that guy who does stuff in those places

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, movies

you!
You, with the *face!*

You're a right smart lookin' cookie, aren't you!
Maybe you can help me.

You see, there is this movie I've been trying to think of; it's right on the tip of my tongue (*jamais vu, si vous voulez*), but I can't remember what it is.

It was that one with that guy. You know! He met that chick, and they fell in love and had a family. Then, this *bad* guy started doin' *bad* stuff and—you guessed it!—all *hell* started breakin' loose!
Well, the family came together and just when you thought they were gonna win, that a-hole catches them. Then he started saying "this is this and that is that," and whatnot, then left to do more bad stuff.
Anyways, all was going well, until—**BAM!**
*More* bad guys!

*You* know the one I'm talking about, right?
One thing I *do* know is that it is **not** one of these movies:

```
    Tootsie
    Ghostbusters (1984)
    When Harry Met Sally...
    Toy Story
    Men in Black
    Chasing Amy
    The Bucket List
    My Super Ex-Girlfriend
    Independence Day
    A Few Good Men
    Zack and Miri Make a Porno
    Undercover Brother
    Blazing Saddles
    Legally Blonde
    Field of Dreams
```

> What's the name of that movie, again?

Comment: At first, I thought you were using PSE like a lame excuse⁯ to identify a movie after MoviesSE discontinued support for identification questions. Then I saw @gnovice's answer and was relieved.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The movie is...

> The Incredibles!

First, it fits the vague description. Second...

> if you pick letters from each movie listed, starting with the first letter of the first movie, the second letter of the second movie, and so on, it spells it out.

Comment: Nice observations. Kudos :D

Comment: Wow. Didn't expect so quick an answer... I have another list of movies ready for another clue, but *not needed*, I guess! +1

Comment: @Chowzen: Oddly enough I was able to guess it from the description alone, and then confirmed it with the list.

Comment: Damn! I intended to be as obscure as possible in my description so as not to give it away, but got too specific, I guess, got carried away.

Comment: @Chowzen: It was fairly obscure, but admittedly I'm a father of 3 so I've seen that movie quite a few times now. :)